# JSON.Net Free JObject resources

Tags: c#, json, resources, json.net

I have some simple code (parser), which I take JSON from web socket:

```
string HTMLOutput = "some reply from server, JSON format"
dynamic JSONOutput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(HTMLOutput);
```

Parsed JSON is really huge. When it starting to deserialize, it takes few GBs of memory. Question is, how can I free resources after parser done its job? I've tried use JSONOutput.Finalize(); but that not working. Any ideas?

Comment: How big (number of characters) is the `HTMLOutput` string?  Can you give a simplified example of what the JSON looks like?  Is it an array with a large number of relatively small records?

Comment: yes, there's lots large number of relatively small records